# Is $\mathbb{C}^{\times}/\mathbb{R}^{\times}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^{\times}/\{\pm 1\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

It's known that $\mathbb{C}^{\times}/\mathbb{R}^{\times}$ is isomorphic to $S^1/\{\pm1\}$ (and the isomorphism is given by $\varphi(z)=z/|z|\{\pm 1\})$. Also, $\mathbb{C}^{\times}$ is isomorphic to $S^1$. So a natural question came to me (witohut no natural answer): is true that $\mathbb{C}^{\times}/\mathbb{R}^{\times}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^{\times}/\{\pm 1\}$? If the answer is yes, how is the isomorphism given (I tried by First Isomorphism Theorem and by writing explicitly without any success), and if not, how to prove it?

Comment: $\mathbb{C}^\times/\mathbb{R}^\times\cong S^1/\{\pm 1\}\cong S^1$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^\times/\{\pm1\}\cong\mathbb{C}^\times$.  $\mathbb{C}^\times$ is not isomorphic to $S^1$.

Comment: @Batominovski: Why not?

Comment: The easiest way to see is that both are (real) Lie groups with different dimensions.

Comment: But we are talking about them just as groups, not as Lie groups.

Comment: Non-isomorphic Lie groups cannot be isomorphic as groups.

Comment: Sure they can.  $\mathbb{R}^2\cong\mathbb{R}$ as groups, for instance.

Comment: Blasted, you are right.

Comment: In that case, $\mathbb{C}^\times \cong S^1$ via $$S^1\cong \mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{R}^2/(\mathbb{Z}\times \{0\})\cong (\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})\times (\mathbb{R}/\{0\})\cong S^1\times\mathbb{R}\cong S^1\times \mathbb{R}_{>0}\cong\mathbb{C}^\times\,.$$  Here, the isomorphism $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\cong \mathbb{R}^2/(\mathbb{Z}\times \{0\})$ comes from $\mathbb{R}\cong\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ is a group with respect to multiplication.

Comment: @Batominovski Just because two subgroups $H,H'\leq G$ are isomorphic does not mean that they will yield isomorphic quotients $G/H$ and $G/H'$.

Comment: My claim doesn't come from that false observation (which I don't know how you use it anyway).  If $\phi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is an isomorphism, then $1\in\mathbb{Z}$ is mapped to $\phi(1)\in\mathbb{R}^2$.  Then, consider $\mathbb{R}^2=\mathbb{R}\phi(1)\times \mathbb{R}x$ for some $x\notin \mathbb{R}\phi(1)$.  Then, we have that isomorphism as $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\cong \phi(\mathbb{R})/\phi(\mathbb{Z})\cong\mathbb{R}^2/\big(\mathbb{Z}\times\{0\} \big)$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is true.  Note that the map $z\mapsto z^2$ is a surjective homomorphism $\mathbb{C}^\times\to\mathbb{C}^\times$ with kernel $\{\pm1\}$, so it gives an isomorphism $\mathbb{C}^\times\cong \mathbb{C}^\times/\{\pm 1\}$.  Similarly, the squaring map also gives an isomorphism $S^1\cong S^1/\{\pm 1\}$.  Thus $\mathbb{C}^\times/\mathbb{R}^\times\cong S^1/\{\pm1\}\cong S^1\cong \mathbb{C}^\times\cong\mathbb{C}^\times/\{\pm1\}$.

Alternatively, you could observe that $\{\pm 1\}$ is the unique subgroup of order $2$ in both $\mathbb{C}^\times$ and in $S^1$, so any isomorphism $\mathbb{C}^\times\to S^1$ must map $\{\pm1\}$ to itself.  It follows that such an isomorphism induces an isomorphism $\mathbb{C}^\times/\{\pm 1\}\to S^1/\{\pm1\}$, so $\mathbb{C}^\times/\mathbb{R}^\times\cong S^1/\{\pm 1\}\cong \mathbb{C}^\times/\{\pm 1\}$.

Comment: Brilliant and elegant! Now this post provide an example of normal subgroups for whoses quocients are isomorphic but they're not (there's a trivial example considering \mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_4$).